# How to use terraform for_each to separate map of objects and get IDs of resources?

Tags: foreach, terraform, failover

in my project I have a two clients and each have a couple of databases. How I can create separate failover group for each client with specific client databases?

This is variables for each client:

```
variable "client" {
  type = map (any)
  default = {
  # Client1 Param
    "client1" = 
      "databases" = {
        "db1" = "true",
        "db2" = "true",
        "db3" = "true",
        },
  },
  # Client2 param
    "client2" = {
      "databases" = {
        "db1" = "true",
        "db2" = "false",
        },
  }
```

Terraform code to create DBs:

```
locals {
  client_databases = flatten([
    for client_key, client in var.client : [
      for database, enabled in client.databases : {
        client_name          = client_key
        database_name        = database
        database_enabled     = enabled
      }
    ]
  ])
}

# ## Create Client Specific Database(s)
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "client_primary" {
  for_each = { for databases in local.client_databases :
    "${databases.client_name}-${databases.database_name}" => databases
    if databases.database_enabled == "true"
  }
  name            = "${each.key}"
  server_id       = azurerm_mssql_server.db["primary"].id
  elastic_pool_id = azurerm_mssql_elasticpool.db["primary"].id

  }
```

Code to create failover group:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "db" {
  for_each            = var.client
  name                = "${lower(azurerm_resource_group.db.name)}-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.db.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.db["primary"].name
  databases           = [for database in azurerm_mssql_database.client_primary : database.id]

  partner_servers {
    id = azurerm_mssql_server.db["secondary"].id
  }

  read_write_endpoint_failover_policy {
    mode          = var.db_failover_policy_mode
    grace_minutes = var.db_failover_policy_grace
  }
```

In this case I create two failover group each of them have all databases:

```
client1-db1
client1-db2
client1-db3
client2-db1
client2-db2
```

How I can create two failover group with client own databases

```
Failover group 1:
client1-db1
client1-db2
client1-db3
Failover group 2:
client2-db1
client2-db2
```

Of course all other needed resources are created!

Comment: Could you publish work terraform code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to declare a separate failover group per client, and then have each failover group include all of the databases for that client.

Your `var.client` seems to already be in a suitable shape for use in `for_each` for resources that should have one instance per client, so there's no need to transform it further for use in that resource, as you've already seen:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "db" {
  for_each            = var.client
  # ...
```

The remaining problem is to generate a suitable value for `databases` which uses the provider-chosen `id` attribute for each `azurerm_mssql_database. That requires reproducing the same compound instance keys used to identify the individual databases:

```
  databases = [
    for db_name, enabled in each.value.databases :
    azurerm_mssql_database.client_primary["${each.key}:${db_name}"].id
    if enabled == "true"
  ]
```

---

Your use of string values to represent boolean values is a little confusing here. I assume you did that because `type = map(any)` was not able to automatically find a suitable single type to use for all elements when you mixed types.

You can avoid that problem by telling Terraform the precise type constraint you expect, which will then allow Terraform to understand how to interpret the given data structure:

```
variable "client" {
  type = map(
    object({
      databases = map(bool)
    })
  )
}
```

The above type constraint removes all of the ambiguity about what `any` is supposed to mean in this context, and thus allows using the more appropriate types for this data structure.

If you do this then you'll need to remove all of your `== "true"` comparisons elsewhere in the module, because `true` is not equal to `"true"` in Terraform. The following is an alternative version of the final example I shared above that's written to work with properly-typed boolean values:

```
  databases = [
    for db_name, enabled in each.value.databases :
    azurerm_mssql_database.client_primary["${each.key}:${db_name}"].id
    if enabled
  ]
```

Using exactly-specified type constraints will typically make a module easier to use and to maintain in future, by making it clear exactly what it requires and ensuring that the values appearing inside the module will always be of the prescribed types.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much for the help! [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins)